# How does JPA infer data type of attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, scala, jpa

A typical JPA entity looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private Calendar anniversary;
  ...
}
```

Note that the data type is not annotated on any of the member attributes.

I just read a note around Hibernate being not so usable with Scala's data types and wondered if we could write some adaptors. I know we can write `UserType`s for Scala types and `UserCollectionType`s for Scala's collections so adaptors may be possible.

The question I have is can I configure these data types somehow so JPA will automatically associate them with corresponding Scala types (e.g. `BigDecimal`'s user type with `BigDecimal` attributes), without having to annotate each attribute with `@Type`?

Comment: I'm not even a beginner in Scala, but to answer your question about types: yes, they are clearly typed in your example. The class and primitive type of each element corresponds to a common data type in most languages so it is simple to reflect on the type and determine it. Scala can run on a JVM so I would assume you have access to the information in one form or another. (The JPA does use reflection in addition to annotations to map entities). I hope that helps. Edit->Clarity: Annotations do not solely determine type in the JPA.

Comment: @DanielChapman, thanks for your answer! no its not really about scala and you are right JPA must be using reflection, but I would like to understand how it actually maps those types (java to SQL) and if that is extensible. I can do `@Type` annotations, but that would be a pain so if I could just tell JPA to also consider my custom types, the code would just as seamlessly as it does for 'regular' Java types!

Comment: I gave a better explanation below-- look into the hibernate tutorials over at JBoss--they're a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing is that the JPA (in most implementations) maps to a relational database so it will map to an SQL type. Thus if you're looking at the entity above it will map to a serialized object if you specify it, but more commonly it will map to a structure.

Let's play with your entity and add an Account to it:

```
@Entity 
public class Account
{
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String password; //no bad don't do this really
}

@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private Account account; //custom type
  private Calendar anniversary;
  ...
}
```

If I run a JPQL query `"SELECT p FROM Person p"` I'm going to get->

```
  Person@AAAAAAAA //some memory with a member child of Account@BBBBBBBB
```

In the database that's going to look like:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  a.*
FROM
  Person p INNER JOIN Account a 
    ON p.account_id = a.id
```

The "custom type" just ended up as a collection of primitives in another table. Generally speaking that's what you want with the JPA. You're trying to map to a RDBMS 99% of the time and you're trying to not use `javax.sql` because you might end up cutting yourself in frustration at the checked exceptions.

Basically: think of it as the database instead of your custom type. That's what the JPA is doing. All the dialects you see in Hibernate or Eclipselink etc... are doing just that. Taking primatives and then saying "When you said `Long` I mean `BigInteger` When you said `String` I think `VARCHAR(2048)`. However you can refine those defaults with annotations like @Column so

```
...
@Column(name="xyz", length="80")
private String name
...
//maps to
COLUMN xyz VARCHAR(80)
```

I'd highly recommend you look at a dialect for a database you know and read the code. It isn't too bad. Hibernate has fantastic documentation for beginners. If you don't know SQL learn it asap if you're working with the JPA. You'll need it.

Comment: thanks again Daniel :-). In the example you have shown, Account would be an entity in the database (table perhaps). What if my custom data type was MyAwesomeList that implements a collection like a  java.util.List implementation and stores accounts. I would like to store accounts and not have a table for the MyAwesomeList. I can do all that using user types in hibernate, i just don't know how I could tell JPA that they should be treated as implicitly as it treats generic java types.

Comment: The JPA is a specification and Hibernate is an implementation (and really it inspired the JPA and has a lot of features that the JPA doesn't). Its possible that the JPA2 supports such behavior--I'm unaware of it though. Here's a question: why use the JPA if hibernate works for you? If it maps in Hibernate and persists you have a solution. Perhaps someone else will have an answer. You should consider look at "JPA persist collection" as keywords and see if someone has a solution you're looking for. I would avoid serialization for long term storage which is what I think hibernate does.

Comment: To clarify (with 11 characters left...) I believe Hibernate serializes the collection into a BLOB and then reads it back. Its a dangerous long term solution because you can't update it. However, there is probably a way to make this work in the JPA.

Comment: JPA + hibernate is just neater than pure hibernate in terms of configuration and hence the temptation :)